# 2 Pepper plants in 1 pot - remove one?

Tags: transplanting, peppers

I bought a pepper plant that has 2 plants right next to each other.  Should I remove or cut out the smaller plant when I transplant into the ground?  Will it grow better with only 1 plant?

Answer (score 1):

I would cut out the smaller/weaker of the two at transplant time. One pepper plant will grow stronger and produce more than two packed right together like that. I would suggest cutting it off near ground level. Attempting to pull it out could break the roots of the other plant.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will take your advice!  Happy gardening :)